# How to show a list in a datagrid cell?

Tags: c#, database, wpf, list, datagrid

I making a simple app for homework, and I have some data handling issues with it.
I have a `DataGrid`, and I uploaded it with data, but one of the rows shows "(collection)" because I uploaded that cells with a list. I would like to ask that how can I display the items of the list in the datagrid?

[image: This is the row with this problem]

I created the datagrid with a List of a class, and the class has an other list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure you have read the [ask] topics. In particular, we need a [mcve] to help you. Please provide your **relevant** XAML markup and model/view-model classes. But be selective! We need a **minimal** example, not all of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to see the items in the list, then the following is a simple way to break your list into text:

```
  void InputToDataGrid(IEnumerable<Records> records)
    {
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            string listText = ""; //resets the text for each row in grid.
            foreach (var item in listVariableToBreak)
            {
                listText += ", " +item.ToString();
            }

            dataGrid.Rows.Add(new[] {columnOne, columnTwo,..., listText});
        }
    }
```

Granted this is a very simple solution, written with some very low level code, that only is a solution for cases where you have a list--you will need to modify it to work with your current situation.

Comment: It helped me, Thank you very much!!